# Vector Space Property

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $S = \{(a_1, a_2): a_1, a_2 \in R\}$. For $(a_1, a_2),(b_1, b_2) \in S$ and $c \in R$, define
>   \begin{align}(a_1, a_2)+(b_1, b_2)&=(a_1 + b_1, a_2 − b_2) \\c(a_1, a_2)&=(ca_1, ca_2)\end{align}

This is an example from Friedberg book. I have studied the properties of vector space but as per one of the property that for each pair of elements $a, b \in F $ and each element $x \in V$, $(a + b)x = ax + bx$, $S$ is not a vector space.

I'm unable to understand how this property fails to hold for $S$

Comment: the "+" operation in vector spaces has to be commutative. This is not the case for the operation you defined

Comment: Can you please explain using some numbers as I'm still not clear about it

Comment: well consider the tuples $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$. On one hand you have that $(1,1)+(2,2) = (1+2,1-2)=(3,-1)$, and on the other hand, you have that $(2,2)+(1,1)=(3,1)$, so $(1,1)+(2,2)\neq(2,2)+(1,1)$. But commutativity of "+" is a requirement of vector spaces

Comment: For each element a in F and each pair of elements x, y in V,
a(x + y) = ax + ay. 
This property holds for the vector space S that I have mentioned
Can you explain the difference between these two properties

Comment: This property may hold in $S$, but $S$ is certainly not a vector space. A vector space has to satisfy $x+y = y+x$, which is definitely not the case for $S$, see my above comments

Comment: I understood that what you're mentioning but I'm unable to understand the difference between the two properties

Comment: There are several properties to satisfy in order to be a vector space. One of them is the "almost distributivity". This is the one expressed by $(a+b)x = ax+bx$. It involves 3 different operations : "+" of the field, "+" of the vector space and "." of the field acting on the vector space. This condition is satisfied by $S$, no problem there. However another condition is that the "+" is commutative, expressed by $x+y=y+x$. It involves only one operation, the "+" of the V.S. This condition fails in $S$, so $S$ is not a V.S.